# DELPHI 2007 & DATASNAP

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, datasnap

I am trying to deploy a datasnap applicationon Windows 7 (Delphi 2007) but I cannot connect. I have register the datasnap server, I see the datasnap server on the client machine (host, server...) during the design-time but when I run the client I am getting catastrofic failure. Is there any solution for this? Thanx

Comment: With at least telling wath the 'catastrofic failure' is I don't think we can help you! Do you get a message indicating something?

Comment: So Datasnap in Delphi 2007 does anybody knows if it works with Windows 7?

Comment: After reading Marco Cantu I included Midalib on Uses both Client & Server but I am still getting "Error Reading ADOConnection. Operation is not allowed in this context " on Server Side & "Catastrophic Failure" on Client Side.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to provide information about your actual question. As it is, all of the information you've provided in your subject is available in the tags (as it should be), and your title adds no useful information. Thanks.

Comment: Delphi 2007 DCOM datasnap works with Windows 7 and Windows 2008(R2). But what Windows version are you using? Home or Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate? The Home version has several network features "neutered".

Comment: I am trying to communicate with 2 machines having Windows 7 & I am using socket component instead of DCOM, running also sctsrvr.exe after registering the server with line command  .....exe/regserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run DCOM datasnap without knowing how DCOM works and how to configure it, you're heading into a lot of trobles. You have to run dcomcnfg.exe and configure your server (and some dcom global settings). Also, when using COM based libraries like ADO you have to know how to setup the hosting application properly. DCOM is a powerful but complex beast.